# How to activate a function in MainActivity after completing Host Card Emulation (HCE) protocol?

Tags: java, android, function, user-interface, hce

I have an Android application where I'm implementing Host **Card Emulation (HCE)** functionality. I have a MainActivity that initiates the HCE script and handles the user interface. After successfully completing the HCE protocol, **I want to activate a specific function or trigger an event in the MainActivity**.

Currently, the HCE script is **connected **to the MainActivity, and the **MainActivity is starter** of HCE script. However, I'm facing challenges in finding a way to control or invoke a function in the MainActivity **once the HCE protocol is finished**.

Here's a simplified overview of my setup:

**MainActivity:** The main entry point of my application that manages the user interface.
**HCE script:** Handles the HCE protocol and communicates with the external NFC reader.

I've tried various approaches to accomplish this, **but I haven't been successful**. Here are a few ideas

**I've explored:**

- Direct function call: I attempted to call a function in the MainActivity directly from the HCE script but faced issues with the scope and context. Is there a way to achieve this?
- Event broadcasting: I considered using broadcast intents to send a custom event from the HCE script to the MainActivity, but I'm unsure how to establish the communication and handle the event in the MainActivity.
- Callback mechanism: I thought about implementing a callback mechanism where the HCE script can notify the MainActivity upon completing the HCE protocol. However, I'm not sure how to set up the callback and handle it in the MainActivity.

I would appreciate any guidance or suggestions on how I can effectively activate a function or trigger an event in the MainActivity from the HCE script. If there's an alternative approach that could achieve the desired result, please let me know.

**Thank you in advance for your help!**